# Technical debt on custom web rule in sonarqube 5.1

Tags: web, annotations, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I am facing issue in technical debt with custom web rules. I have web plugin but no technical debt is assigned to rules. I want code or annotation through which i can assign some constat/issue value to each rule and can calculate debt from that.

I used following anotations while creating web rules.

```
@Rule

@WebRule

@RuleTags
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at how this is implemented on the [numerous SonarQube open-source plugins](https://github.com/SonarSource) that are developed by SonarSource and the SonarQube community.

For instance, on [the Java plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/), you can look a some classes like [AnonymousClassShouldBeLambdaCheck](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/AnonymousClassShouldBeLambdaCheck.java). You will see that the following annotations are used to declare the technical debt:

```
import org.sonar.squidbridge.annotations.SqaleConstantRemediation;
import org.sonar.squidbridge.annotations.SqaleSubCharacteristic;
```